# How to filter with multiple conditions in a pandas dataframe that include unwanted entries?

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I currently have the following code:

```
df[(df.Edition == 2004) & (df.Discipline == "Athletics") | (df.Discipline == "Aquatics")]
```

However, this (rightfully) returns every entry where Edition is 2004, and discipline is EITHER Athletics or Aquatics (thus giving me entries where Edition is not 2004). However, I want to pull all entries where Discipline is Athletics OR Aquatics but the Edition is locked to 2004. How can I query that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your parenthesis right:

```
>>> df[(df.Edition == 2004) & 
       ((df.Discipline == "Athletics") | 
       (df.Discipline == "Aquatics"))]
```

Comment: FYI: this is not a typo, but a change in logic. Typo has a different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isin`

```py
df[(df.Edition == 2004) & df.Discipline.isin(["Athletics", "Aquatics"])]
```